# Remove WWW from output using the code below

Tags: php, wordpress, url

```
<?php wpfp_link() ?>
<small>
<?php 
    $url = esc_url( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link', true ) );
    $parse = parse_url($url);
    print $parse['host'];
?>
```

**The above code gives output:**

```
www.example.com
```

What I want is to remove the WWW part so that the output is

```
emaple.com
```

Comment: Use this `$only_domain = str_replace("www.", "", $parse['host']);`

Comment: @FrayneKonok thank you it worked perfectly :)

Comment: You need to have the habit of accepting answer, so people come to help you.

Comment: @FrayneKonok you are right. Thanks again :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use `str_replace` function.

```
$parse['host'] = 'www.example.com';
$only_domain = str_replace("www.", "", $parse['host']); //example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If(substr($parse,0,3)=="www")  $parse = substr($parse,3)
//or
preg_match("/\.?(.*\..*)/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fD4

Edit: oops forgot a ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to use something like this,

```
 <?php 
  $url = esc_url( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_source_link', true ) );
  $parse = parse_url($url);

  $email  = 'name@example.com';
  $domain = strstr($parse, '.');
  echo $domain; // prints example.com
 ?>
```

This function check for the first occurrence of . and remove other string , so if you have url like , **http://www.example.com** than also this will gives out put **example.com**